# Flash Player 11 hides some content

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3

We have a Flex application which is build against the 3.3 SDK. It has been in production for more than a year without any problems, till yesterday. We got a bug report yesterday that some content is invisible which prevents the user from completing an assignment. I looked into the problem and I have narrowed it down to Flash Player 11. Unfortunately it got me no closer to solving the problem.

The part of the application that is giving problems is a separate .SWC which is loaded in a SWFLoader object. This is placed on a Canvas which in turn is shown to the user via the PopupManager.

[This is what it looks like when I view it in FireFox 10.0.2 with Flash Player 10,0,45,2 (click for image)](http://i857.photobucket.com/albums/ab139/ictoanen/FlashPlayer/dcl_fp10.png)

[And this is what it looks like when I view it with Flash Player 11,1,102,62 in Chrome 17.0.963.56 (click for image)](http://i857.photobucket.com/albums/ab139/ictoanen/FlashPlayer/dcl_fp11.png)

As you can see I am missing the checkboxes, two buttons and the checkpoint in the middle. The checkpoints drops in from the top of the screen and sometimes you can see parts of it. It looks like there is something invisible on top of this. In the Flash Player 11 version I am able to click on the checkboxes that are invisible and this does trigger the expected behavior so I know the mouse clicks are handles properly. Same goes for the buttons 'Vorige' (previous) and 'Volgende' (next), even though you can't see them I can still navigate between states.

I have check if disabling the hard acceleration in Flash Player 11 made a difference but unfortunately it didn't. I also thought it could be the preloader that is blocking out part of the screen but the position seems all wrong and I am not having any problems with other external .SWC files that are presented to the user.

I am guessing the problems lies somewhere in the external .SWC that is loaded but I was wondering, has anyone else has seen this kind of behaviour with Flash Player 11?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem in Flash Player Version 10. and i have just rollback the work that i have did and got a smaller problem with the CSS. I am not sure but just do that once. and check the work a some interval. You might get overcome that situation.

Comment: I have created a small Flex 3.3 project with just the SWFLoader. At start up I have it load the .SWC that is giving trouble in the bigger project. Even in this compact form it exhibits the same behaviour as I have described in my original post. At least I know for sure the problem is in the external .SWC which does make it easier to debug the problem.

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with the mask we were using. It was applied to the object without first adding it to the stage. We had to add a single line of code to make it work on FP11.

Comment: congratulation... Might be the hard time to do that but you prove the fact that hard and intelligent work always wins.. congrats again..